# Using numpy arrays to avoid for loops - combinatorics

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There's got to be a more pythonic way of doing:

```
r = np.arange(100)
results = []

for i in r:
    for j in r:
        for k in r:
            for l in r:

                #Here f is some predefined function
                if f(i,j,k,l) < 5.0:
                     results.append(f(i,j,k,l))
```

I'm sure using arrays can simplify this somehow, I'm just not sure how. Thanks!

Comment: You skipped f but it is important here (to see if it can be vectorized).

Comment: f is one of the eigenvalues of a matrix whose elements are functions of the i,j,k,l. Is that enough info?

Comment: What you really need to do is rewrite `f` so it accepts and uses a 4d array directly. :)  As long as `f` only works with 4 scalar inputs, you are stuck with some sort of Pythonic iteration like this.

Comment: note that said 4d array would be about a GB in size...

Answer (score 5):

Use `itertools` cartesian product:

```
import itertools
r = np.arange(100)
results = []
for (i,j,k,l) in itertools.product(r,repeat=4):
    if f(i,j,k,l) < 5.0:
         results.append(f(i,j,k,l))
```

Or even more compact way, using list comprehension:

```
[ f(i,j,k,l) for (i,j,k,l) in itertools.product(r,repeat=4) if f(i,j,k,l) < 5.0 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now is this any faster than using for loops, or is just a nicer way of writing things? I'm hopefully looking for a solution that is the most computationally efficient.

Comment: @cracka31 I added a more compact way. I don't think that you can do it **significantly** more efficient.

Comment: You can cut the number of `f()` calls in half with this respelling: `[x for t in itertools.product(r,repeat=4) for x in [f(*t)] if x < 5.0 ]`.  The `for x in singleton_list` part is a sneaky way to embed an assignment statement.

Comment: @cracka31, you're calling `f()` 100 million times.  Unless `f()` is amazingly cheap, the costs of setting up the 100 million argument lists (no matter how that's coded) are going to be minor compared to the time spent _in_ `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loops and the if statement can be avoided by using NumPy's [`fromfunction`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy.fromfunction) and [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). The proposed approach is wrapped in `comb_np(n)`, whereas the `itertools`-based solution proposed by @Ohad Eytan is wrapped in `comb_it(n)`. For convenience, the number of iterations on each for loop (`100` in your example) is passed as an argument to both functions (`n`). To comparatively analize these two approaches I used a simple polinomical function `f(x, y, z, t)`.

```
from numpy import fromfunction
from itertools import product
from numpy import arange

def f(x, y, z, t):
    return x + 2*y + 3*z + 4*t

def comb_np(n):
    arr = fromfunction(f, (n,)*4)
    return arr[arr < 5.0]

def comb_it(n):
    return [f(i,j,k,l) for (i,j,k,l) in product(arange(n),repeat=4) if f(i,j,k,l) < 5.0]
```

Sample run:

```
In [1302]: comb_np(10)
Out[1302]: array([ 0.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  4.,  3.,  2.,  4.,  3.,  4.])

In [1303]: comb_it(10)
Out[1303]: [0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4]
```

Both approaches produce the same result. So far, so good. But let us now assess whether there is any difference in terms of efficiency:

```
In [1304]: import timeit

In [1305]: timeit.timeit("comb_np(10)", setup="from numpy import fromfunction;from __main__ import comb_np, f", number=1)
Out[1305]: 0.0008685288485139608

In [1306]: timeit.timeit("comb_it(10)", setup="from itertools import product;from numpy import arange;from __main__ import comb_it, f", number=1)
Out[1306]: 0.05153228418203071

In [1307]: timeit.timeit("comb_np(100)", setup="from numpy import fromfunction;from __main__ import comb_np, f", number=1)
Out[1307]: 3.4775129712652415

In [1308]: timeit.timeit("comb_it(100)", setup="from itertools import product;from numpy import arange;from __main__ import comb_it, f", number=1)
Out[1308]: 354.3811327822914
```

From the results above it clearly emerges that in this particular problem NumPy's vectorized code outperforms iterators by roughly two orders of magnitude.

---

Interestingly enough, I found that simply replacing NumPy's `arange` by the built-in function `range` the performance of `comb_it` is dramatically improved:

```
def comb_it2(n):
    return [f(i,j,k,l) for (i,j,k,l) in product(range(n),repeat=4) if f(i,j,k,l) < 5.0]
```

Results:

```
In [1381]: comb_it2(10)
Out[1381]: [0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4]

In [1382]: timeit.timeit("comb_it2(10)", setup="from itertools import product;from __main__ import comb_it2, f", number=1)
Out[1382]: 0.009133451094385237

In [1383]: timeit.timeit("comb_it2(100)", setup="from itertools import product;from __main__ import comb_it2, f", number=1)
Out[1383]: 32.556062019226374
```